# topViewController in iOS 12 / Xcode 10

Tags: xcode10, ios12, swift4.2

So, I've updated to Xcode 10 and iOS 12 today and now I'm getting the following error message when I call topViewController from UINavigationController:

> Ambiguous use of 'topViewController'

```
if let myVC = navigationController.topViewController as? MyViewController {}
```

Even though the following code works just fine.

```
if let myVC = navigationController.visibleViewController as? MyViewController {}
```

Does anyone know any changes in iOS 12 regarding this?

Comment: the topViewController is not change in iOS12. I tested in Xcode10, iOS12 and it has nothing wrong. What is your `navigationController`?

Comment: UINavigationController

Comment: do you have another variable with the name `topViewController`?

Comment: Actually there is a class that extends `UINavigationController` and an extension of `UIViewController` that has a variable called `topViewController`. It's legacy code so I'm not sure why it was created like this. But what changed in Xcode 10/iOS 12 that made this code doesn't work anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest you this func for getting topViewContoller as an extension. Easy to use as you guess.

```
extension UIApplication {
    class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
UIApplication.topViewController()
```